# How inbox and sent folder messages are linked in MailKit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I try to get messages in inbox folder that where not replied.

At first I used some field in MimeMessage `InReplyTo` and it was helful.

But today I discovered that some messages that already had replies had this field `InReplyTo` with null statment. Is there another way to get messages that wheren´t replied?

Comment: If the mail client on the other end that sends a reply does not set that field you won't get it. So simply said you can't rely on InReplyTo to detect replies as not all mail clients use it.

Comment: Detecting a reply presumably needs a combination of checking the In-Reply-To, References and Subject headers. Checking the subject might have the risk of false positives so only do that if its good enough or needed in the context you want to use that.